Компиляция в коде Python
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы программа создавала py файл, а потом компилировала в exe, но без python (не установленого)

Вам придётся принести с собой докер или виртуальную машину. Или реализовать удалённый сервер-компилятор и связываться с ним. Так или иначе Питон запустить придётся, вам остаётся только решить как это сделать.

@StanislavVolodarskiy виртуалка имееться, но как так сделать?

Поместить все файлы для компиляции на диск/каталог видимый из виртуалки. Внутри виртуалки собрать exe. Готово.

без установленого пайтона

Так или иначе Питон запустить придётся
